# Alamofire Swift HTTPPost login and JSON response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Can someone help me with a brief tutorial about the logging in to the web service by passing about 4 parameters and receiving response in JSON using Alamofire and Swift?
Thanks.

Comment: A quick google search would give you this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial,  http://nshipster.com/alamofire/

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general. Alomofire has great docs on how to do this. I don't think I can write a better tutorial here. Nevertheless here is some example code.
I'm getting a filtered selection of companies from a REST-API :

```
    let connection = DefaultConnection.connection
    let companySelection = "/companies"

    // configure parameters for our query
    var parameters = ["columns":"id,name,short_name,active,language_code,remarks,created_at,updated_at"]

    // filter(s)

    parameters["filter"] = "[\"deleted_at\", \"filters/null\"]"

    // limit (used for debugging purposes)
    //parameters["limit"] = "25"

    //sort
    parameters["sort"] = "name"

    // load the whole shebang
    connection.loadData(companySelection,  parameters:parameters, importHandler: handleImportedData)
```

where DefaultConnection is a singleton (so I can reuse that code for all my queries) :

```
 func loadData (dataPath : String, parameters:Dictionary <String,String>, importHandler: ((data:JSON) -> Void)?)  {

        let urlPath = baseURL +  dataPath

        let start = NSDate()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath, parameters: parameters, headers: ["X-API-KEY": apiKey, "Content-type application":"json", "Accept application" : "json"]).responseJSON() {
            (req,res, data, error) in

            if error != nil {
   ....
```